# Help to get taxonomy term views to display custom fields based on term name not ID

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

I am having a situation where I would like to have a views page display a result set based on a taxonomy term.

I followed this tutorial here. Although this is for 6, it works perfectly for D7.

http://www.leveltendesign.com/blog/dustin-currie/link-taxonomy-terms-custom-views-drupal

It works great! It's exactly what I want, except for one issue - I have to use the ID, and I want to use the term name.

I did change the the token to use the [name] field instead. I'm 99% there. The problem is now terms with two words are broken up by spaces instead of hyphens.

Basically I am trying to get this to print out the custom url with hyphens instead of spaces. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're missing the link to the tutorial you reference.

Comment: whoops, ok there you go.